# Importing More Than 65.535 rows to MS Access from Excel

Tags: vba, excel, ms-access-2013

I'm running the following code to import an entire sheet from excel to access, the sheet has 77k rows, but Access is importing only 65.535, any clur on how to fix it? Both Excel and Access are version 2013.

```
Function importa()

    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Dim inicio As String
    Dim fim As String


 DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, _
    "NOMEBASE", Application.CurrentProject.Path() + "\Abre_Envio_Novo_Layout.xlsm", True, "Menu!BJ25:BM26"



    Set db = CurrentDb()
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset("NOMEBASE")

    inicio = rs.Fields(2).Value
    fim = rs.Fields(3).Value



DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12, _
    "BASE", Application.CurrentProject.Path() + "\Abre_Envio_Novo_Layout.xlsm", True, "Mailing_Recebido!A:AX"


    rs.Close

End Function
```

Comment: Not sure of the exact answer but 65,566 is the row limit for pre 2007 excel workbooks. What version of excel is spreadsheet made in?

Comment: Gareth Both were made on excel and access 2013.

@pnuts I tried both *excel14 e *excel15 but then it returns a "ISAM" error =(

Answer (score 1):

`acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12` should be `acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml` for importing an Excel 2010 workbook.

Comment: Just tried it, "Runtime Error 3170: Couldn't find installable ISAM"

Comment: That means that you do not have the DLL installed.  Are you running Office 2010?

Comment: I'm running office 2013, would you happen to know which DLL I need?

Comment: See if this registry key exists: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Jet\*.0\Engines\Excel`  If it does the DLL should be listed there.

Comment: Mine is this:

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Excel

There says:

C:\Windows\system32\msexcl40.dll

But I do have this DLL, my Windows is 64 bits tho, could this be the cause?

Comment: [MS Jet DB](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=13255) The files should be available here.

Comment: Are you using 64-bit office?  If so, you'll have numerous problems with Jet.  Try to exclude the `acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12` and use the parameter names to use all of the other parameters like: `ParameterName:=ParameterValue`

Comment: @jbarker2160 To avoid confusion, please refer to the newer Access Database Engine as "[the] Access Database Engine" or "ACE", not "Jet". Jet is the older engine (.mdb only, 32-bit only, installed as part of Windows).

Comment: @DiegoPatrocinio For what it's worth I just imported 77,000 rows from an .xlsx file into Access 2013 using `DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet acImport, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel12Xml, "my77k", "C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\77k.xlsx", True`. It worked fine.

Answer (score -1):

```
docmd.transfertext.........
```

please use this command in MS access if u wants to transfer more than 65536 rows in access